# Allowing user to select report parameter in BIRT

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, birt

how to build birt reports with parameters from view page:instead of birts default input box, here user provides required parameter from codeigniter view page.I have built a view page to input parameter. I have used and tested birts feature to allow user input! Now i want to input form codeigniter controller.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to run BIRT report directly from your application without using BIRT default window for filling out report filters (parameters). This can be done by specifying report parameters within URL with which you are calling BIRT report.

Example: http:// host : port /birt/run?__report=report_name.rptdesign&parameter1=parameter1value&parameter2=parameter2value...

Comment: thanks:u got exactly what i want! but where can i set such parameter?

Comment: \o/ You need to compose URL inside your application, i.e. under your codeigniter view page (you wrote you managed to built view page to input parameters). codeigniter is not my domain. :)